# fadeToggle on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div which shows/hides with `display:none/block` by clicking on an id `#cart`. The div opens and closes by clicking on element with the id but I want to close the div on body click too. How can I do it please?

Code I am using is below:

```
jQuery("#cart").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle( "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#cart, body").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a listener to the entire window and check for clicks. When there is a click, we check which element has been clicked and check on whether it's the element. We repeat this for the parent element as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function checkClickOutsiteElement(clickedElement, elementToCheck){
                var iterator = clickedElement;
                while(true){

                    // The click was in the element.
                    if( iterator === elementToCheck )
                        return;

                    // Go to the parent.
                    if( !iterator.parentElement ){
                        alert('outside menu');
                        return;
                    }

                    iterator = iterator.parentElement;
                }
            }

            window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                checkClickOutsiteElement(event.target, document.getElementById('menu'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="menu" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="not_menu" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have this div which shows/hides with display:none/block by clicking
>   on an id #cart. The div opens and closes by clicking on element with
>   the id but I want to close the div on body click too.

In vanilla javascript, you can:

- write a function to show / hide the div
- add a click event listener to `#cart`
- add a click event listener to `body`

**Working Example:**

```js
// Grab #cart
const cart = document.getElementById('cart');

// Grab .myDiv
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0];

// Function to toggle .myDiv
const toggleMyDiv = (e) => {

  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
   
    myDiv.dataset.display = (myDiv.dataset.display === 'show') ? 'hide' : 'show';
  }
}

// Add Click Event Listener to #cart
cart.addEventListener('click', toggleMyDiv, false);
document.body.addEventListener('click', toggleMyDiv, false);
```

```css
body,
#cart {
cursor: pointer;
}

div {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

#cart {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.div {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.div[data-display="show"] {
opacity: 1;
}

.div[data-display="hide"] {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart">Cart</div>
<div class="div show" data-display="show">myDiv</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want two separate functions, since your cart button should toggle both ways, but the body click handler should only toggle *out*.

Protip: `on()` isn't doing anything for you that `click()` wouldn't, the way you're using it. The latter is a bit cleaner.

```
jQuery("#cart").click(function() {
    jQuery(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle("fast");
});

jQuery("body").click(function() {
    jQuery(".shopping-cart").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Protip 2: Easily and safely alias `jQuery` to `$` like so:

```
jQuery(function($) { // document ready with dollar alias
    $("#cart").click(function() {
    ...
});
```